# Ionic - app.run called multiple times

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am puzzled, I try to initialize some stuff at application startup, but it seems that the .run element is called multiple times, every time a page changes.

```
var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
starter.run(function ($rootScope) {
    if ($rootScope.ifVarInitialized != 1) {
        alert('This is a run element.');
        $rootScope.ifVarInitialized = 1;
    }
});
```

What's more, I wrote above to try to supress multiple execution of some code, but the alert pops up multiple times also, so are the $rootScope values somehow resetted as well? Is this a normal behaviour?

I tried the same with .config - identical outcome.

Versions:
Ionic: 1.3.1
IONIC CLI: 2.1.17
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0

Comment: where did you write starter.run()?

Comment: In app.js file. In the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried just .run without the starter?

Comment: Yes, and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you did not close your module properly . close variable `var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])` properly or use . directly to run that code snippet. you diddn't mention why you use $rootScope.ifVarInitialized in your app becuase you didn't initialize it and in run you will not get ifVarInitialized  value,

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       alert("run is working");
      if ($rootScope.ifVarInitialized != 1) {
            alert('This is a run element.');
            $rootScope.ifVarInitialized = 1;
        }
      });
    })
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is connected with the fact that in the project are used swithing between sites as a normal html links? Maybe I should instead use changing states or views?

Comment: Well, I cannot see any error. The thing is that with your code, the code inside .run element is not executed at all, even if I leave only the alert command.

Comment: So, to sum it up, placing the following, and the alert command is never called.

Comment: angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            alert('This is a run element.');
    });
})

Comment: If you're finished with your trial and error solution please add some explanation why your code solved the askers problem. Code-only answers is frown upon.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.